# CakePHP 3 - Application rules for unique field

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to add an application rule which prevents duplicate rows being saved.

I followed the book about [creating unique field rules](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#creating-unique-field-rules) but it doesn't seem to work, or I'm doing something wrong.

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Rule\IsUnique;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;

class CustomersTable extends Table

    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        return $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email']));
    }
}
```

Just performing a straight save:

```
$this->loadModel('Customers');
$this->Customers->save($customer);
```

Having looked at the [IsUnique class source code](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/source-class-Cake.ORM.Rule.IsUnique.html#19-84), I get that it should be getting called via its `__invoke()` magic method but my application is still throwing an exception due to the duplicate row trying to save.

Is there anything incorrect with my code above?

Comment: Maybe `$this->Customers` is not an instance of your `CustomersTable` subclass, but an auto-table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you just forget to add the validation class and entity

It may look like this

```
       namespace App\Model\Table;

       use App\Model\Entity\Customer;// 

       use Cake\ORM\Query;
       use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
       use Cake\ORM\Table;

       use Cake\Validation\Validator;

      class CustomersTable extends Table
       {
           public function initialize(array $config)
           {
             $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');//
             //$this->table('customers'); *u can also specify ur table like this 
           }

           public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
           {
              $validator
                 ->notEmpty('email')
                 ->requirePresence('email')

              return $validator;
          }



          public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
          {
            $rules->add($rules->isUnique(array('email')));
            return $rules;
          }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, this was along the correct lines. I believe it was using an auto-generated base Entity, so as soon as I created an actual Entity class for the table it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own custom validator for this. Also you should check if it matches the current user id for example if you want to let it work on updates.

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator->add('email', 'uniqueEmail', [
        'rule' => function ($value, $context) {
            if(isset($context['data']['id'])) {
                return !$this->exists(['email' => $value, 'id !=' => $context['data']['id']]);
            }
            return !$this->exists(['email' => $value]);
        },
        'message' => 'Email address already registered', 
    ]);
    return $validator;
}
```

Comment: Why should anyone do this, when correct usage of the existing isUnique rule would suffice?